# Extracting text in Bash script

Tags: bash

I have header files that have a lot of #define statements like: `#define GPSVersion 0x000;`

I would like to write a Bash script to extract the text `GPSVersion` into a file. But how do I use grep to do that? I can find the pattern `#define` but how do I find the text following `#define` ?   Thanks.

Comment: Did you ask for the particular GPSVersion define or for all the defines in the file?

Comment: @DavidCosta I should have made it clearer, I meant all defines in the file. I want to find the text that follows  #define. The GPSVersion text is one example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "#define GPSVersion 0x000;" | awk '{print $2}'

cat file.h | grep ^'#define' | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: I have many lines like this, so the generic version is to use `awk \`{print $2}\`1 ?

Comment: This may print extraneous lines that contain `#define` in comments.  Use `'^#define` to print only lines that _start_ with `#define`.

Using `cat` starts an extra unnecessary process.  `grep $PATTERN < $FILE` is more efficient.

Since you're always printing the second field, `awk` is overkill; `cut` is far more efficient.

Comment: @AdamLiss You are probably right. I gave the up check before I ran the code in the answer above. (My wife called me to breakfast).

Comment: I've edited the code and added some @AdamLiss recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one-liner that uses Perl instead of grep:

```
 perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if $_ =~ /#define \b(\w+?)\b.*/' < header.h
```

where `header.h` is the file that has `#define GPSVersion 0x000` in it.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. `cat`your file. (an `echo` in sample)
2. filter lines including ones that starts by #define
3. get second field

Command:

```
echo "#define GPSVersion 0x000;" | grep ^"#defin" | cut -d" " -f2
```

Comment: This will print the second field, which is `GPSVersion`

Comment: It is -- thanks for the correction!  I misread the question, thinking all of the headers defined various values for `GPSVersion` and that the OP wanted to collect the actual version numbers.  I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$find /path/to/root/of/source/tree -name '*.h' |
  xargs grep '^#define.*GPSVersion' | cut -d' ' -f 2
```

**Explanation:**

The `find` command will print all files in the source tree whose names end in `.h` -- that is, all of your header files.

The `xargs` command passes the file names to `grep`, which will print all the lines that begin with `#define`, followed by one or more characters, followed by `GPSVersion`.

The `cut` command will print the 2nd field (the text that's being `#define`d), using the space characters as delimiters between fields.

Answer (score 0):

I think this works for you:

```
grep -r '#define[[:space:]]*GPSVERSION[[:space:]].*' . | tr -s ' \t' '\t' | cut -f 3
```

`grep -r` : scans ALL the files in the specified directory and subdirectories
`'#define[[:space:]]*GPSVERSION[[:space:]].*'` : is a regexp that matches all the #define directives, ignoring the whitespacing and considering only #defines that have a value assigned to them.

Grep prints its output, then the output is passed to `tr -s ' \t' '\t'` which convert blanks to something suitable for `cut`

Finally `cut -f3` prints only the desired value of the define.

It works well except: comment defines (//#define) and filenames with spaces in them.